# Selenium Python can't open a second page while using chrome webbrowser

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, loading

I am using Selenium to open different pages of a site. Have tried multiple times but the browser does not open a second webpage after the initial GET call. Have tried on Chrome. Below is the screenshot of the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPkZu.png)

Looking forward to your support on it.

Comment: Does it work manually ?

Comment: Please post the URL and your code

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes, manually it's working

Comment: @Ram URL is - https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Second-Hand-Car-Dealers/nct-10425724